# Meaning of --> if (typeof options === 'string' && methods[options])

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Can someone explain what the expression

methods[options]

evaluates in this code?

$.fn[pluginname] = function(options) {

```
    if (typeof options === 'string' **&& methods[options])** {
        alert("Mirko in");
        var inited = TRUE;
        this.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).data(pluginname)) {
                return inited = FALSE;
            }
        });
```

When is this expression ever true? I thought in javascript you don't have associative arrays.

For information:
- methods ist just an object type (--> var methods = {method1: function()..., method2: function ()...}
- options is also an object that is handed over to customize the plugin.

Thanks

Comment: `methods[options]` will evaluate to `true`, when the `methods` object contains a property with the name of whatever value is in `options`. e.g, if `methods = { 'foo': .... }`, then `methods['foo'] ==  true`, but `methods['bar'] === false`

Comment: It is true when the argument _options_ has type string and the _methods_ object has _options_ as a key. If options is not a key, the expression has value _undefined_ and so the whole expression is false.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

`methods[options]` accesses the value in the methods object associated with a key equal to the string value of the `options` variable.  If a truthy value is stored there, it would return true.  e.g.,

```
  var methods = {yes: 'hello'}
  var options = 'yes'
  (typeof options === 'string' && methods[options]) //evaluates as true

  options = 'no'
  (typeof options === 'string' && methods[options]) //evaluates as false
```

The second one evaluates as false because `methods['no']` returns `undefined`.  However, in your question you said `options` is an object- if that's always true, then the first half of the boolean `typeof options === 'string'` will always be false and cause the whole expression to be false.  I'd imagine that the plugin gives the option to pass in a string or object value for `options`.