# typeof options == 'object' && options, why does this return the object value?

Tags: javascript

Why does the code below work? 
Why does the object in the variable `options` get assigned to `i_identify_as_boolean` instead of a boolean?

I would expect a boolean value in this case. I would expect this to work if I would write `typeof foo == 'object' ? foo : null` but not in this way. In this way I would expect a boolean.

So why does it work? I've tried reading the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operatoren/typeof) documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482081/meaning-of-if-typeof-options-string-methodsoptions) but nothing illustrates this behavior.

```js
let options = {hello: 'world'};
let i_identify_as_boolean = typeof options == 'object' && options;
let i_identify_as_object = typeof options == 'object' ? options : null;
console.log(i_identify_as_object.hello);
console.log(i_identify_as_boolean.hello);
```

Comment: This is a weird naming for `as_boolean` considering that this property stores an object, not boolean. Basically, thanks to the way JS executes this code, this code is just an an *(ugly?)* equivalent to `typeof options == 'object' ? options : false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all conditions are truthy it will always set it as the last truthy variable.

```
let x = true && 5
x returns 5;
```

if you want to use the variable as a boolean value you can double negate it so that it returns a boolean 
`!!x`